# Исключить экран из приложения

Tags: android

Есть андроид приложение, надо исключить возможность установки приложения на 7 дюймовые планшеты. На телефоны (смартфоны) и планшеты 10 дюймов что б ставилось, а на 7 дюймов нет, как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установить совместимость по размеру экрана в дюймах нельзя. Можно по типу размера экрана - small, normal, large и x-large, которые базируются на разрешении:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Для того, чтобы объявить, что ваше приложение совместимо только с определёнными типами экранов, надо объявить в манифесте блок `compatible-screens`:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

Это описано в разделе "[Distributing to Specific Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)" официальной документации.

Comment: Этот код я видел в документации и про compatible-screens читал, как будет выглядеть код для моей задачи? В инете встречал инфу что в compatible-screens вносят те экраны которые надо исключить, так ли это?

Comment: Ваша задача неосуществима, вам придётся либо от неё отказаться, либо изменить её условия. Инфу вы встречали ложную. Цитата из документации "_Each <screen> element specifies a screen configuration with which your application is compatible_" явно на это указывает.

Comment: Что бы исключить 7'' надо не указывать large размер.